# EJB server error on Wildfly 8.0

Tags: ejb, server, wildfly

I have just started learning EJB and just wanted to execute my first code.
However, I am unable to remove this error:

> Error-11:24:22,065 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (default task-3) JBAS011806:
>   Channel end notification received, closing channel Channel ID 4fb1d052
>   (inbound) of Remoting connection 6e42fa05 to null

I am using Java 1.8 with wildfly 8.0

**Code ClientBean**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws CommunicationException {
    try {
         Context context = getInitialContext();
         Hello remote=(Hello)context.lookup("HelloBean/remote");
         System.out.println(remote.Hello());
    } 
    catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Context getInitialContext() throws javax.naming.NamingException {
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http-remoting://localhost:8080");
    properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
    return new javax.naming.InitialContext(properties);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to invoke your EJB and you see this error after that ?
Also please add credentials to InitialContext Properties ,like below

properties.put("java.naming.security.principal", "user");
properties.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "pass");

You can add this user to wildfly , using addUser.bat/sh scripts. It will ask for something like "use this user for EJB remote communication " , say yes for that.